# Excel- How to find all the M's in an M*N relationship?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Suppose i have spreadsheet data like the format below. I want to find the names of employees who work for a particular manager. Can someone help me out with how to proceed with this. I have been able to get the number of employees for a particular manager using pivots. But getting their individual names has posed a problem. I'm sorry if the question is too nooby. Im still new to this.

```
    Name            Department     Reporting Mgr
Neeraj Kanth        Support        Vinod Kumar Bhugari
Manoj Soni          Technical      Sunil Kumar Sharma
Amar Deep Gupta     Technical      Sukhdev Singh
Suresh Kapoor       Management     Anil Baid
Deepak Arora        Technical      Munish Gupta
Anjan Chakrabarty   Technical      Sukhdev Singh
Pravin Kumar Jha    Support        Vinod Kumar Bhugari
Shipra Shekhar      BD             Anil Baid
Vinod Parate        Technical      Anchit Sharma
B. Vamsi Krishna    Technical      Munish Gupta
Raman Kumar Raman   Technical      Sunil Kumar Sharma
Prashant Kumar      Technical      Sukhdev Singh
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use Filter and apply the filter to reporting Mgr by choosing the manager you need, only the corresponding Name will show

Comment: yea I cant do that... There are over 50 managers... What I need is like a formula that gives me all the individual employees for all the managers at one go

Comment: In Pivot put Reporting Manager as top level filter and put Name as Row level filter rather than Values level summary. Now when you choose a manager name at top level filter, the list of subordinates shall be seen instead of count.

Comment: thank you it does do the work but i want something better to help reduce the time. I need a formula for data conversion that does it all in one go

Comment: You can put Reporting Manager as first row and Name as second row under Rows in Pivot Table. Do not put anything under Top Level Filter in that case

Comment: Filtering the list is exactly what you need. It will hide all rows except the ones the filter is set to. No pivot table, just data->filter

Comment: If you need to see all employees grouped to their respective manager, just sort on the manager column.

Comment: yea thats right this works....thanks a lot  LPChip...pat2015...

Comment: but i was hoping for a direct formula or function i could use to directly transform it...cuz i had to do over 50 copy pastes haha...wish there was a way to directly convert the pivots into rows